# Post method in spring controller is not working

Tags: spring, controller

I have developed a form in jsp and in the form if user clicks submit button then the controller should capture the parameters but unfortunately it is not working.

```
/*<form action="http://localhost:8080/school" method="POST">*/
<form action="/school" method="POST">
                School name: <input type="text" id="school" name="school" />
                <input type="hidden" value="${firstName}" name = "firstName"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="${lastName}" name = "lastName"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

The controller function is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/school", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void setSchool(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        String firstName= request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName= request.getParameter("lastName");
        String school= request.getParameter("school");

        String status = userController.setSchool(firstName, lastName, school);
        try {
        if(!status.equals("SUCCESS")) {

                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, status);
        }
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/getInsideSchool?school="+school+"&firstName="+firstName+"&lastName="+lastName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When i click on submit button in the form i cannot reach the controller function. How do i map url or fix this issue?
Thank you

Comment: are you sure, you don't have any mapping top of the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/school" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a POJO

```
class User {
    private String school;
    private String  firstName;
    private String  lastName;

    // getter setter constructor 
}
```

Then write the controller method as following

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/school", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String home(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    System.out.println(user.toString());
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```